# Building an Interface for User Generated Graphs

Tags: data-visualization

I've researched this issue and have not found anything to meet my needs. I am worried that perhaps I'm using the wrong terms.

I would like to build a website interface that allows users to select different variables and then have those variables dynamical or automatically graphed or charted. I need it to be able to handle 100+ variables (there could be limits to how many were charted at one time) and display the data on a bar graph, pie chart, or line graph based on the users preference.

What would I need to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use either Flash and ActionScript or JavaScript and HTML5.

I've been looking to do something like this too actually.

Need a facility for parsing the data, and then working out scales/ratios and to represent the data in a coherent way, with labels. Then you need to scale the shapes your using according to the scale that the data is covering, and for the sizes to naturally be proportional.